# How to insert json from API to snowflake database using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to insert json string to Snowflake variant column in ado.net C#, but I totally have no idea how to implement it due to so few instruction on the internet. For example,

```
var json = {
  "student": {
  "name": "John Smith",
  "age": 10
  }
}

dataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestDemo SELECT PARSE_JSON(NOTIFICATION) FROM VALUES();";
```

Here I use the snowfalke connector for .NET on the github.https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net

I want to know the syntax how to write in the commandtext. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake on .Net is not my thing, but boiling one example from github might work.
The query below will at least allow the insertion, hopefully binding the string parameter also works:

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    conn.Open();

    IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into TestDemo select parse_json(?)";

    var p1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p1.ParameterName = "1";
    p1.Value = "{""student"": ""John Smith""}";
    p1.DbType = DbType.String;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

    var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, count);             

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. That works. I find that the ParameterName must be "1" or "2", these numbers to mark the position in blinding values. Thank you again.
And I don't think IDataReader and Assert.AreEqual are necessary here.

Comment: I prefer to use positional bind variables :1, :2, etc instead of ?, but I'm not sure how that works with .Net.  IDataReader and Assert are not necessary, but the assert was in the original code, and I believe it checks that exactly 1 row was inserted.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your suggestions. Really really help me.